# How to use a feature set as an output parameter in a Python Toolbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-toolbox

I'm having trouble setting a "Feature Set" output parameter from a .pyt ..
I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 SP1.

Here’s a short script that can be invoked either from a classic toolbox (thru the main() function; one setup with same parameters [here](http://goo.gl/wQPkn)), or as a .pyt .. it works as expected when invoked from a classic toolbox, but does not as a .pyt:

```
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.label = “FeatureSet Output Test”
        self.alias = “”
        self.tools = [Test]

class Test(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.label = “Test1”
        self.description = “Output a few points in a feature set”
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):

        params = []

        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = “FS Output”, name = “fsOutput”,
            datatype = “Feature Set”, parameterType = “Derived”, direction = “Output”)
        params.append(param0)

        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName = “JSON Output”, name = “strOutput”,
            datatype = “String”, parameterType = “Derived”, direction = “Output”)
        params.append(param1)

        return params

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):

        gdbPath = ‘in_memory’
        featureClassName = ‘points’
        featureClass = ‘{}/{}’.format(gdbPath, featureClassName)

        try:
            arcpy.AddMessage(‘Creating a point feature class with 1 text attribute’)

            if arcpy.Exists(featureClass):
                arcpy.Delete_management(featureClass)

            arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(
                out_path=gdbPath, out_name=featureClassName, geometry_type=’POINT’,
                spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))

            arcpy.AddField_management(
                in_table=featureClass,
                field_name=’Attribute1’, field_type=’TEXT’)

            arcpy.AddMessage(‘Inserting a couple points’)
            with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(featureClass, (‘SHAPE@XY’, ‘Attribute1’)) as cur:
                cur.insertRow(((1, 1), ‘point at 1, 1’))
                cur.insertRow(((2, 2), ‘point at 2, 2’))

            arcpy.AddMessage(‘Setting the output parameters’)
            featureSet = arcpy.FeatureSet(featureClass)


            # Has no effect in either .tbx or .pyt case .. no error, just does nothing.
            parameters[0].value = featureSet

            # Does what's expected for classic .tbx; does nothing
            #   for .pyt .. again, no error, just does nothing.
            #   You can comment this line out for testing the first set method ..
            arcpy.SetParameter(0, featureSet)

            # This works fine in both .tbx and .pyt
            parameters[1].value = featureSet.JSON

        except Exception as e:
            arcpy.AddError(str(e))


def main():
    tool = Test()
    tool.execute(arcpy.GetParameterInfo(), None)

if __name__ == ‘__main__’:
    main()
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong .. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've only ever used feature sets for input and thought that, rather than output, was what they were designed for. It will be a while before I can look at this so I'm going to include links to your posting on the [**ArcGIS Discussion Forum**](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/85505-python-toolbox-Feature-Set-output-parameter) and the [**Help Page**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001n000000) to assist later.

Comment: I got a similar answer in post you linked to; using "datatype = 'Feature Class'" instead of "datatype = 'Feature Set'" does fix my problem. If you can offer any insight into what the real difference between a 'Feature Set' vs 'Feature Class' is, I'll gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only ever used Feature Sets for input and thought that, rather than output, was what they were designed for.

My understanding of Feature Sets comes from **[here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w00000023000000)**.

From what I can tell they are simplified Feature Classes but simplified in what ways I do not know.